# Make points for Google Maps using GeoJSON.Net in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I’m using Visual Studio 2013.  As a simple example, I want to produce GeoJSON for a collection of 50 water wells (points).  The structure of the existing data looks like this:

```
class WaterWell
{
    public int WaterWellId { get; set; }
    public int Diameter { get; set; }
    public int Depth { get; set; }
    public string Lat { get; set; }
    public string Lng { get; set; }
}
```

I might typically work with the collection of water wells like this:

```
var myWaterWells = new List<WaterWell>();
// blah, blah
```

Because I'll be displaying the GeoJSON in Google Maps, it must be compliant with the http://geojson.org standard.

I’ve installed the GeoJSON.Net package to Visual Studio from Nuget.  Surprisingly, however, after much googling, I can find no GeoJSON.Net C# examples anywhere.
So, my question is this:   How to use GeoJSON.Net in C# to serialize my collection of 50 water wells to GeoJSON?

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem, this function from "GeoJSON.Net.Tests" project.
You can debug and see the actualJson.

The 2 lines that I remarked related to json file.

```
public void Can_Serialize_Point_Feature()
{
    var geometry = new Point(new GeographicPosition(1, 2));
    //var expectedJson = GetExpectedJson();

    var actualJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Net.Feature.Feature(geometry));

    //JsonAssert.AreEqual(expectedJson, actualJson);
 }
```

You need create point objects from your Lat and Lng properties

This is my example code I wrote for you:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var points = new List<Point>
        {
            new Point(new GeographicPosition(52.370725881211314, 4.889259338378906)),
            new Point(new GeographicPosition(52.3711451105601, 4.895267486572266)),
            new Point(new GeographicPosition(52.36931095278263, 4.892091751098633)),
            new Point(new GeographicPosition(52.370725881211314, 4.889259338378906))
        };

        var multiPoint = new MultiPoint(points);

        var actualJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Feature(multiPoint, null));
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this I keep getting a json convert error: `'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriterException`