# Create GeoJson c#

Tags: c#, json, google-maps, geojson

I'm trying to create a simple example for creating GeoJson file.

I read the tool GeoJson.NET, but I do not quite understand how to create this file.

I'll be glad if someone could give me a small example of creating GeoJson with a number of Points, and explain me how I can use it without creating a file, but to transfer the Json to JavaScript file because I want to make a call to the database every user entry system for give the data in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem

First Read my answer from the following link: [Make points for Google Maps using GeoJSON.Net in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639806/make-points-for-google-maps-using-geojson-net-in-c-sharp/41331186#41331186)

After creating GeoJson should return it to JavaScript and then have to use the following line:

```
map.data.addGeoJson(JSON.parse(result));
```